# OpenLayers WMS layer doesn't load

Tags: javascript, openlayers, gis, wms

I use the following block of JavaScript to try to show a WMS layer. I'm using OpenLayers 2.8.

The map's base layer (Openstreetmap) shows correctly, it zooms to the correct area, the "pyramid" layer is shown in the layer switcher, but *no request to its WMS service is ever made* (so the fact that the URL, styles and params are dummies shouldn't matter -- it never even attempts to get them).

OpenLayers *does* try to get a WMS layer once I pan or zoom far enough so that the Gulf of Guinea is in view (but all my data is in the Netherlands). This suggests a projection problem (WGS84's (0, 0) point is there), but I don't understand why OpenLayers doesn't even try to fetch a map layer elsewhere. My data is in EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) projection.

```
/*global $, OpenLayers */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    $(function () {
        $(".map").each(function () {
            var div = $(this);

            var data_bounds = div.attr("data-bounds");
            console.log("data_bounds: " + data_bounds);

            if (data_bounds !== "") {
                var map = new OpenLayers.Map(div.attr("id"), {
                    projection: "EPSG:3857"});

                var extent = JSON.parse(data_bounds);
                var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    extent.minx, extent.miny,
                    extent.maxx, extent.maxy);

                map.addLayer(
                    new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
                        "OpenStreetMap NL",
                        "http://tile.openstreetmap.nl/tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                        {buffer: 0}));

                map.addLayer(
                    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                        "pyramid", "http://rasterserver.local:5000/wms", {
                            layers: "test",
                            styles: "test"
                        }, {
                            singleTile: true,
                            isBaseLayer: false,
                            displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
                            units: 'm'
                        }));

                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
                map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Edit: the 'data_bounds' console print prints (with some added formatting):

```
data_bounds: {
    "minx": 582918.5701295201,
    "miny": 6923595.841021758,
    "maxx": 821926.9006116659,
    "maxy": 7079960.166533174
}
```

It zooms to the correct region in the north of the Netherlands, so I don't think the problem is there.

Since posting, I found out that if I don't use the OSM layer, and instead use the WMS layer as baselayer, it works. So perhaps there's some incompatibility with a OSM baselayer and a WMS layer added to it? But then I don't get that it does seem to do something near WGS84 (0, 0).

Comment: What are you bounds, or extent, as you have it in your code?

Comment: I added the bounds console output to the question.

Comment: Have you tried using 900913, the older designation of spherical mercator, instead of 3857, seeing as you are on OL 2.8?

Comment: I didn't, but a few seconds ago I managed to find an answer -- it works once I add a maxExtent to the map. No idea why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great. You haven't done mapping till you've loaded something in Nebraska and it appears in the sea of Ghana :-)

Comment: And for someone who may one day find this question with the same issue: I tried the 900913 suggestion, but it doesn't fix it either.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually managed to fix this by giving the map an explicit `maxExtent`:

```
var extent = JSON.parse(data_bounds);
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
    extent.minx, extent.miny,
    extent.maxx, extent.maxy);

var map = new OpenLayers.Map(div.attr("id"), {
    projection: "EPSG:3857",
    maxExtent: bounds
});
```

Oddly enough this doesn't limit the user's ability to pan and zoom around the world, but it does make the overlay work...